# Swift Error: UIAnimationOptions in UIView.animateWithDuration function

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am trying to test out the UIView.animateWithDuration function with UISwipeGestureRecognizer. However, I kept getting the error "Could not find member CurveEaseOut"

Even though, it is one of the variables under UIViewAnimationOptions.

Can anyone please advise me what is wrong with my UIView.animateWithDuration function??? Thanks.

```
@IBAction func handleSwipe(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    var original_pos: CGPoint!

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        original_pos = sender.view?.center
        println("original position is \(original_pos)")
    }

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        if sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down && sender == label1 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.2, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {sender.view?.center.x = self.label2.center.x}, completion: { finished in println("Napkins opened!")})
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That code compiles without an error for me - what Xcode version are you on?

Comment: I am using xcode 6 GM. May I know which version are you using?

Comment: fix `sender.view?.center.x` to `(sender.view?)!.center.x`. And there will not be error, believe me :) Because animation block must not be `nil`. In your code `self.view?` may cause `nil`, because it is optional property

Comment: One of the Weirdest Solutions I've seen. But Thanks Anyway, it Does Work